# 3ds max : Model Optimisation

Tags: 3ds-max

Is it possible in 3ds max to decimate a mesh while keeping it as close to the original as possible down to a 1mm difference?

Is it possible to measure this distance?

Cheers

Comment: 1mm tolerance on what sized base mesh? What percentage change would that represent?